# Meaning of "Land of five figure" and "the wheels are turning upstairs"

Tags: phrase-meaning

From the book *Rainmaker*:

> Simple Rudy. This is Tennessee. Land of five figure.

I don't get the meaning of *five figure*.

And I couldn't find the meaning of the bolded phrase:

> In spite of the hangover, **the wheels are turning upstairs**.

Comment: Please, ask one question at a time.

Comment: I agree with Glorfindel's comment :/. It was a little involved to answer both questions together. Despite being from the same source, they required separate, different definitions.

Comment: Should it be edited to include 'verdicts'? It changes the entire question, imo.

Answer (score 9):

1. "In spite of the hangover, [I am] still *thinking, analyzing*."

   - "[...wheels turning](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/see-someone-s-wheels-turning)," Dictionary.com.
   - *The Rainmaker*, John Grisham

> By "upstairs," the speaker means "in his brain" ("[Upstairs](http://upstairs.urbanup.com/4316799#.WNo-AK5kcds)," Definition Five, urbandictionary.com).
>
> When he says the "wheels are turning" upstairs, he means that the wheels in his head are turning.
>
> And if the wheels in his head are turning, it means that the wheels in his head are at work.
>
> And if the wheels in his head are turning and at work, it means that he's thinking.
>
> A related phrase would be that "[the gears are turning](http://www.definition-of.com/Gears+are+turning)" (see the second definition, especially).
>
> One such man whose wheels are turning:
>
> [image: Insert appropriate and timely pop culture reference]

2. "Simple, Rudy. This is Tennessee. [Tennessee is the] land of the five-*digit* ***judgements*** [for lawsuits for punitive damages]."

   - "[Figure](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/figure)," Synonyms, Cambridge Dictionary.
   - "[Verdict](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=verdict%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Z0TaWLDmEc348AfLw7mACw)," Synonyms, Google.com
   - *The Rainmaker*, John Grisham

> If you understand that a verdict is a judgement in a lawsuit...
>
> ...and that on occasion, one may receive [monies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punitive_damages#United_States) (punitive damages) for successful lawsuits...
>
> ...while also remembering that the amount of money one person makes in Tennessee is not that high ([number 40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_income#States_ranked_by_per_capita_income) out of 50 states)...
>
> ...then you should have no trouble understanding that Tennessee is the land of verdicts where the punitive damages awarded are only five-figures ($10,000-$99,999).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer even with a proper example picture. That helps me a lot .

Comment: Next time I will aske a question at a time. Sorry for that .

Comment: @user51561, heh, thank *you* for the question and the opportunity to put in that picture :D. Had just felt that the picture had been appropriate, given [what's in theaters right now](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=beauty+and+the+beast+showtimes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=wEzaWPfkLsP48AeDv5C4Bg)....

Answer (score 5):

**[The wheels are turning](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+wheels+are+turning)** is an idiom quite easy to find. It means **"something is happening"** or **"something that you say which means a process is starting to happen"**

- In spite of the hangover, **something is happening** *(preparations - i guess)* upstairs.

As **Teacher KSHuang** has added in his answer there is another meaning to this phrase **"The wheels are turning upstairs"**.

- [Upstairs](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upstairs) - 3rd definition is **"in the head"**

So it may as well mean that **"something is happening in the head"**.

---

By the way it should be **The Land of five figure verdicts**.

**The Rainmaker by John Grisham**

> “Simple, Rudy. This is Tennessee. Land of the five-figure verdicts.
>   Nobody gets punitive damages here. The juries are extremely
>   conservative. Per capita income is pretty low, so the jurors have
>   great difficulty making rich people out of their neighbors. Memphis is
>   an especially tough place to get a decent verdict.”

Comment: You may want to take a look at the definition for "upstairs" in my answer to help explain the concept more clearly for the OP.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Btw I knew this definition. It's quite an interesting sentence. I've gotta use it some day.

Comment: Yes, it is :). The two idioms go well together.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang **"in my head"** is just one many definitions of the word **"upstairs"**  and not an idiom. Is it not? So basically that's an idiom+intellectual definition.

Comment: Heh, [an age-old question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/39985/211575) and [an age-old poll](https://www.usingenglish.com/poll/475.html) for a tale as old as time.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang You have opened my eyes my friend!